# Pipeline and redirection understanding

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Please explain this script (from [ABSG. Ch. 20](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)):

```
exec 3>&1                              # Save current "value" of stdout.
ls -l 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | grep bad 3>&-    # Close fd 3 for 'grep' (but not 'ls').
#              ^^^^   ^^^^
exec 3>&-                              # Now close it for the remainder of the script
```

Currently I imagine how it works:

1. script connects fd/3 output to stdout
2. pipeline connects stdout of `ls` to stdin of `grep` (fd/3 is inherited by both processes)
3. redirerection of stderr of `ls` to stdout
4. stdout of `ls` is changed to fd/3 (so `grep` process has no more `ls` output, only errors)
5. fd/3 is closed for `ls`

Is this the exactly sequence of redirections?

Can't understand why I see output of `ls` if there are no errors and we close fd/3 where stdout is redirected.

What is the purpose of closing fd/3 for `grep` process (`grep bad **3>&-**`)?

Comment: I think I've got it now. On step 2 with pipelining stdout of `ls` was **replaced** with unnamed pipe connected to `grep`'s stdin. So I could see output of `ls` because its stdout was restored from fd/3 with redirection (>&3 3>&-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps a bit if you think the file descriptors as variables that accept a file as a value (or call it an i/o stream) and the order they appear is the order of their evaluation.

What happens in the above example is:

1) The script starts (as per default and unless otherwise inherited) with the following

```
fd/0 = stdin    # that's the keyboard
fd/1 = stdout   # that's the screen
fd/2 = stderr   # the screen again, but different stream
```

2) The `exec` command translates to declaring a new variable and assigning a value

```
fd/3 = fd/1  # same as stdout
```

So now, two file descriptors have the value stdout, i.e. both can be used to print to the screen.

3) before `ls` is executed and inherits all open file descriptors, the following setup happens

```
ls.fd/1 = grep.fd/0    # pipe gets precedence, ls.fd/1 writes to grep.stdin
ls.fd/2 = ls.fd/1      # ls.fd/2 writes to grep.stdin 
ls.fd/1 = ls.fd/3      # ls.fd/1 writes to stdout
ls.fd/3 = closed       # fd/3 will not be inherited by `ls`
```

fd/3 has served the purpose of keeping the stdout value long enough to return it to fd/1. So now everything that `ls` sends to fd/1 goes to stdout and not `grep`'s stdin.

The order is important, e.g. if we'd run `ls -l >&3 2>&1 3>&-`, ls.fd/2 would write to stdout instead of `grep`'s stdin.

4) fd/3 for `grep` is closed and not inherited. It would be unused anyway. `grep` can only filter error messages from `ls`

The example provided in ABSG is probably not the most helpful and the comment "*Close fd 3 for 'grep' (but not 'ls')*" is a bit misleading. You can interpret it as: "*for the ls, pass the value of ls.fd/3 to ls.fd/1 before unsetting so it won't get closed*".